# I sometimes go for <a walk><walks> (after supper)

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> (1) I sometimes go for a walk.
>
> (2) I sometimes go for walks.
>
> (3) I sometimes go for a walk after supper.
>
> (4) I sometimes go for walks after supper.

**Question:** Which are correct?

Sentence (4) sounds a little odd to me.

The following sentence motivated me to start this thread:

> I always go for walks with my pet. ([source](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%A7%81%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E8%AA%B2%E3%81%AF%E7%8A%AC%E3%81%A8%E6%95%A3%E6%AD%A9%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8))

Comment: You can only take one walk at a time, so (1) and (3) seem the most logical to me.

Comment: walks is OK in certain circumstances but no so much here. Dog owners take their dogs for walks here everyday.